# Cypress: unit testing the pure React component is throwing error

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, cypress

I am writing unit tests using Cypress for my React JS web application. I can write functional tests using Cypress. But I also need to write the unit tests for my presentation components in my app. So I am using this Cypress wrapper for React, https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/tree/master/npm/react. But, when I write the unit test for my component, it is throwing an error. Following is how I installed and wrote the unit test for my pure component.

First I installed the required libraries running the following command.

```
npm install --save-dev cypress @cypress/react @cypress/webpack-dev-server
```

Then I added the following line into the cypress/plugins/index.js

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {
    require('@cypress/react/plugins/react-scripts')(on, config)
  // `on` is used to hook into various events Cypress emits
  // `config` is the resolved Cypress config
}
```

Then I created a test file called, no_result.spec.js with the following code.

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from '@cypress/react';
import NoResult from "../../../src/components/NoResult";

describe("NoResult Component", () => {

    it ('should display message', () => {
        mount(<NoResult message={"No data available."} />);

        cy.contains('No data available').should('be.visible');
    })
})
```

Then I opened the cypress and run that no_result.js test and I got the following error.

```
AssertionError
Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: #__cy_root, but never found it.

Because this error occurred during a before each hook we are skipping all of the remaining tests.
node_modules/@cypress/react/dist/cypress-react.esm-bundler.js:317:1
  315 |     return cy.then(function () {
  316 |         var selector = "#" + ROOT_ID;
> 317 |         return cy.get(selector, { log: false }).then(function ($el) {
      | ^
  318 |             var wasUnmounted = unmountComponentAtNode($el[0]);
  319 |             if (wasUnmounted && options.log) {
  320 |                 cy.log('Unmounted component at', $el);
```

What is missing in my configuration and how can I fix it?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run react component tests as basic cypress integration tests. Component tests require a bit different setup, you can read more about it here: https://www.cypress.io/blog/2021/04/06/cypress-component-testing-react/